# UBUNTU14.04 could not be loaded due to GRUB Error

Tags: boot, bootloader

I installed UBUNTU14.04 in ACER Laptop after completing the installation the GRUB is not working, How can I install the GRUB separately?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you installing an "old" distribution from 2014? The current LTS Version is 16.04.
Here how to install Grub: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Whether it's an old release is irrelevant. And anyway, EOL for 14.04 is in 2019.

Comment: It's not obligatory to use the latest version. 14.04 is supported, it's stable enough (unlike 16.04) and it will be supported until 2019. Both of them generally work well with GRUB.